# Как убрать скобки с кавычками?

Tags: python

```
def user_hist_pass(self, zip_file):
        result_pass = ""
        with self.connection:
            for i in self.cursor.execute("SELECT `zip_pay`, `pass_pay` FROM `product` WHERE `zip_file` = ?", (zip_file,)):
                result_pass += f'{i[1]}'
            return result_pass
```

выводит :

```
('0', '0')
```

Comment: Куда выводит? У вас тут нет вывода. А так то это кортеж.

Comment: В сообщении ботом выводит

Comment: вот спросите бота, как и что вообще он выводит, а потом приходите сюда с этой информацией.

Answer (score 0):

Это кортеж. Элементы кортежа можно использовать по индексу `result_pass[0], result_pass[1]` или просто в виде строки с помощью `" ".join(result_pass)`